# Discord js, TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a User nor a Role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot, which when a command is entered, it will change the permission of a channel for only that user. However, when trying to overwrite the permission I keep getting this type error.

> TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a User nor a Role.

I keep getting the error, pointing towards the message.member.id ,any help would be appreciated all questions relating to this are to do with roles rather than users.

```
        const permissions = new Permissions([  
        'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
        'EMBED_LINKS',
        'ATTACH_FILES',
        'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
        'MANAGE_ROLES',
        ]);

        const nextChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "b2");
        nextChannel.overwritePermissions([
            {
                id: message.member.id,
                deny: permissions,
            },
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you did not provide a `User` nor a `Role` you provided a `GuildMember`

You need to replace `message.member.id` with `message.user.id`

Comment: Thank you, however when trying this, it gave me the following error. ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: have you tried doing `message.author`? without `.id`

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? And what version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution below - Taken that you are on v11

```
nextChannel.overwritePermissions(message.author.id
            {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false
            },
        );
```

I hope this helped you continue.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. However, this came up with the same error.

Comment: Apologies for the misinformation before. This should solve your problem. However, I don't know how well `new Permissions([])` will work in this.